# AWS Instance starts but can't access SolOS cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, solace

Total noob to AWS and Solace here.

I can get my AWS instance running with the Solace AMI and login but can not access the Solace CLI as "SolOS solace application not running" Attempts to manually start the daemon appear to be successful until tested.

Ideas? Thx.

Comment: I have no idea what solace is, but people ask some variation of "I just started an EC2 instance and can't access some service running on it" many times a day on here. The solution in almost every case is to open the appropriate ports in the EC2 security group.

Comment: Solace is a virtual message router, but thanks for the feedback, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is commonly seen on startup when the user specifies an AWS instance type that does not meet the minimum requirements.
The Solace VMR requires at least a t2.medium instance.

If the above is not true, then please provide the output of `sudo tail -n 100 /var/lib/docker/volumes/jail/_data/logs/debug.log` so that more information can be obtained.

Comment: BOOM! Thank you so much for the timely and helpful response! That was in fact the issue; upsized my instance and I'm off!